# Insert multiple rows at a time in YII

Tags: php, yii

I have gone through the http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.table

I did not understand what this means:

```
$items=$this->getItemsToUpdate();
```

what is this `$this->getItemsToUpdate()` function?

I am trying to insert dynamic rows at a time. I have used jquery for creating the data but I don't know how to insert them into the database.

Comment: This doesn't look like Javascript. I think it is PHP.

Answer (score 9):

Yii supports to add multiple records.

Use this....

```
 $alertStatus[] = array(
                        'db_field_name1' => $value1,
                        'db_field_name1' => $value2, 
                        'created_on' => new CDbExpression('NOW()'),
                        'modified_on' => new CDbExpression('NOW()')
                    );
 $connection = Yii::app()->db->getSchema()->getCommandBuilder();
 $command = $connection->createMultipleInsertCommand('table_name', $alertStatus);
            $command->execute();
```

$alertStatus array should contains all the fields of database

Comment: you can make it positive response

Answer (score 1):

If you're not constrained to working with Active Records, you could use DAO to execute an appropriate SQL insert statement for inserting multiple rows. You can find an example of such a statement here:

[Insert multiple records into MySQL with a single query](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-insert-multiple-records/)

Once you have your insert statement as a string (which can be constructed dynamically using a loop in case you don't know in advance how many rows you need to insert), you can execute it like this:

```
$sql = 'INSERT statement goes here';
$connection = Yii::app() -> db;
$command = $connection -> createCommand($sql);
$command -> execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the same issue.

As far as I know Yii doesn't have default function to insert multiple rows.

So I've created one in `CdbCommand` class (framework/db/CDbCommand.php) :

```
/**
 * Creates and executes an INSERT SQL statement for several rows.
 * @param string $table the table that new rows will be inserted into.
 * @param array $array_columns the array of column datas array(array(name=>value,...),...) to be inserted into the table.
 * @return integer number of rows affected by the execution.
 */
public function insertSeveral($table, $array_columns)
{
    $sql = '';
    $params = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($array_columns as $columns) {
        $names = array();
        $placeholders = array();
        foreach ($columns as $name => $value) {
            if (!$i) {
                $names[] = $this->_connection->quoteColumnName($name);
            }
            if ($value instanceof CDbExpression) {
                $placeholders[] = $value->expression;
                foreach ($value->params as $n => $v)
                    $params[$n] = $v;
            } else {
                $placeholders[] = ':' . $name . $i;
                $params[':' . $name . $i] = $value;
            }
        }
        if (!$i) {
            $sql = 'INSERT INTO ' . $this->_connection->quoteTableName($table)
                . ' (' . implode(', ', $names) . ') VALUES ('
                . implode(', ', $placeholders) . ')';
        } else {
            $sql .= ',(' . implode(', ', $placeholders) . ')';
        }
        $i++;
    }
    return $this->setText($sql)->execute($params);
}
```

Usage:

```
$rows = array(
            array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'John'),
            array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Mark')
);
$command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand();
$command->insertSeveral('users', $rows);
```

---

**Update**

As [Nabi K.A.Z.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1407491/nabi-k-a-z) mentioned it is really much better not to touch source code of framework.
In my project I've actually created class MyCDbCommand (that extends *CDbCommand*) and I've created MyCDBConnection (that extends *CDbConnection*).

**MyCDbCommand** (extending CDbCommand):

```
class MyCDbCommand extends CDbCommand
{
    protected $_connection;

    public function __construct(CDbConnection $connection, $query = null)
    {
        $this->_connection = $connection;
        parent::__construct($connection, $query);
    }

    /**
     * Creates and executes an INSERT SQL statement for several rows.
     * @param string $table the table that new rows will be inserted into.
     * @param array $array_columns the array of column datas array(array(name=>value,...),...) to be inserted into the table.
     * @return integer number of rows affected by the execution.
     */
    public function insertSeveral($table, $array_columns)
    {
        $sql    = '';
        $params = array();
        $i      = 0;
        foreach ($array_columns as $columns) {
            $names        = array();
            $placeholders = array();
            foreach ($columns as $name => $value) {
                if (!$i) {
                    $names[] = $this->_connection->quoteColumnName($name);
                }
                if ($value instanceof CDbExpression) {
                    $placeholders[] = $value->expression;
                    foreach ($value->params as $n => $v) {
                        $params[$n] = $v;
                    }
                } else {
                    $placeholders[]           = ':' . $name . $i;
                    $params[':' . $name . $i] = $value;
                }
            }
            if (!$i) {
                $sql = 'INSERT INTO ' . $this->_connection->quoteTableName($table)
                    . ' (' . implode(', ', $names) . ') VALUES ('
                    . implode(', ', $placeholders) . ')';
            } else {
                $sql .= ',(' . implode(', ', $placeholders) . ')';
            }
            $i++;
        }
        return !empty($sql) ? $this->setText($sql)->execute($params) : 0;
    }

}
```

**MyCDBConnection** (extending CDbConnection and using MyCDbCommand):

```
class MyCDbConnection extends CDbConnection
{

    public function createCommand($query = null)
    {
        $this->setActive(true);
        return new MyCDbCommand($this, $query);
    }
}
```

Then I've changed **config file** (/protected/config/main.php).
I've changed CDbConnection to MyCDbConnection there:

```
...
'components'=>array(
    ...
    'db' => array(
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dname',
        'username'         => 'user',
        'password'         => 'password',
        'charset'          => 'utf8',
        'class'            => 'MyCDbConnection', // Change default CDbConnection class to MyCDbConnection
    ),
    ...
    )
...
```

And here you go. We did it without touching a core framework and you can use it the same way as before.

Comment: What about escaping values?

Comment: @kouton can you be more specific?

Comment: My bad, didn't notice the param binding in the loop.

Comment: This throws SQL error when number of columns is different for some rows.

Answer (score 0):

The above code from [Pigalev Pavel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22009891/1407491) was great.

But that need to modify core framework and this is bad!

So, I write a independent class.

Put this code in `components` folder under `GeneralRepository.php` file name.

```
<?php
class GeneralRepository
{
    /**
     * Creates and executes an INSERT SQL statement for several rows.
     * 
     * Usage:
     * $rows = array(
     *      array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'John'),
     *      array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Mark')
     * );
     * GeneralRepository::insertSeveral(User::model()->tableName(), $rows);
     * 
     * @param string $table the table that new rows will be inserted into.
     * @param array $array_columns the array of column datas array(array(name=>value,...),...) to be inserted into the table.
     * @return integer number of rows affected by the execution.
     */
    public static function insertSeveral($table, $array_columns)
    {
        $connection = Yii::app()->db;
        $sql = '';
        $params = array();
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($array_columns as $columns) {
            $names = array();
            $placeholders = array();
            foreach ($columns as $name => $value) {
                if (!$i) {
                    $names[] = $connection->quoteColumnName($name);
                }
                if ($value instanceof CDbExpression) {
                    $placeholders[] = $value->expression;
                    foreach ($value->params as $n => $v)
                        $params[$n] = $v;
                } else {
                    $placeholders[] = ':' . $name . $i;
                    $params[':' . $name . $i] = $value;
                }
            }
            if (!$i) {
                $sql = 'INSERT INTO ' . $connection->quoteTableName($table)
                . ' (' . implode(', ', $names) . ') VALUES ('
                . implode(', ', $placeholders) . ')';
            } else {
                $sql .= ',(' . implode(', ', $placeholders) . ')';
            }
            $i++;
        }
        $command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);
        return $command->execute($params);
    }
}
```

And usage anywhere:

```
$rows = array(
    array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'John'),
    array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Mark')
);
GeneralRepository::insertSeveral(User::model()->tableName(), $rows);
```

Comment: Thanks! I've forgot to change my answer here but in my project I also end up making a new class. In a bit different way but very alike. I've updated my answer.